# Laravel 5 - Manually logging in a user without password

Tags: laravel, authentication, oauth, laravel-5

I want to login users after authenticating them using OAuth and Google account without entering any password.

I know `Auth::login` functon can do such action but I don't know how to get the user instance while they haven't been authenticated yet.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could look at https://github.com/adamwathan/eloquent-oauth  - either to use as a package or to see how he is doing it?

Answer (score 24):

You can 'manually' log a user in in two diefferent ways:

```
// log user in by ID
Auth::loginUsingId([id of user]);
```

Or

```
$user = User::find([id here]);
// or maybe
$user = User::whereUsername([username here])->first();

// and then
Auth::login($user);
```

See [the documentation for authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#other-authentication-methods).